# Angular 2 CurrencyPipe space between currency and number?

Tags: angular

I noticed that there is a pipe called CurrencyPipe in Angular 2, which will filter some decimals from a number. This also adds the ISO currency indicator, ie 'USD' or any other local currency.

My problem is that the output is displayed like this:

```
USD123
```

Without space between USD and 123, is this really the preferred behavior? Do I have to write my own pipe for this or is there something that I can do to add a space?

Here is some code:

```
<span>{{ product.price | currency:'USD' }}</span>
```

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: How about: `<span>{{ product.price | currency:'USD ' }}</span>`

Comment: Doesn't look like there is support for that. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/CurrencyPipe-class.html

Comment: `<span>USD {{ product.price|number:'1.2-2'}}</span>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible since the `CurrencyPipe` relies on `Intl.NumberFormat` and there is no options for this.

That said you can switch to display `$` instead of `USD` with the `symbolDisplay` parameter set to `true`:

```
<span>{{ product.price | currency:'USD':true }}</span>
```

This will display: `$123` which is a bit better ;-) If this doesn't suit you, you need to implement a custom pipe to format your number...

See these links for more details:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/facade/intl.ts#L70
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: I see. Is there anyone that find this pipe useful then? I can not see that one might want to display the currency without a space... I'll have to find another solution I guess.

Answer (score 17):

You may solve this problem using a bit of clever CSS using the [first-letter pseudo element](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/), add a class to your span:

```
<span class="price">{{ product.price | currency:'USD':true }}</span>
```

and in your css add:

```
.price {
  display: inline-block;
}

.price::first-letter {
  padding-right: 0.3em;
}
```

The first rule makes sure your price in a block container box (`::first-letter` does work on `inline` display blocks), and the second rule adds a bit of extra padding after the currency symbol.

You can tweak this to your liking ...

Comment: its only for symbol not for whole word like USD

Comment: Users of this asnwer should be wary of any currency which is not normally displayed with a symbol. For example, CHF would look like `C HF` given the above style.

Answer (score 10):

Do you really need to use currency pipe? You can always separate the currency from the amount :

`<span class="price">{{ product.currency }} {{ product.price|number:'1.2-2'}}</span>`

or in your case :

`<span class="price">USD {{ product.price|number:'1.2-2'}}</span>`

Comment: This only works if you don't change languages. In german the currency comes after the number.

Answer (score 8):

Make your own custom currency pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({ name: 'myCurrency' })
export class MyCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(num: any, currencyCode: string, showSymbol: boolean, digits: string): any {
        let value = new CurrencyPipe(navigator.language).transform(num, currencyCode, showSymbol, digits);
        let firstDigit = value.match(/\d/);
        let symbol = value.slice(0, firstDigit.index);
        let amount = value.slice(firstDigit.index);   
        return symbol + " " + amount;
    }
}
```

and use it in
**HTML** like

```
{{amount | myCurrency: currencyCode :true:'1.0-2'}}
```

Comment: Nice. But what about cultures that are used to have the amount first and the currency symbol at the end?

Comment: This should be the answer - you can easily adjust this function if your only worry is putting the symbol at the end or front.

Answer (score 8):

You can override the pipe as follows. 
Make sure you include this in the module

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";


@Pipe({name: 'currency'})
export class MyCurrencyPipe extends CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, currencyCode: string, symbolDisplay: boolean, digits: string): string {
    const currencyFormat = super.transform(value, currencyCode, symbolDisplay, digits);
    const firstDigit = currencyFormat.search(/\d/);
    return currencyFormat.substring(0, firstDigit) + ' ' + currencyFormat.substr(firstDigit);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Changes for Angular v5 and up

---

The **DISPLAY** parameter is changed from `boolean` to `string`

> display   string | boolean
>
> The format for the currency indicator. One of the following:
>
> - code: Show the code (such as USD).
> - symbol(default): Show the symbol (such as $).
> - symbol-narrow: Use the narrow symbol for locales that have two symbols for their currency. For example, the Canadian dollar CAD has
>     the symbol CA$ and the symbol-narrow $. If the locale has no narrow
>     symbol, uses the standard symbol for the locale.
> - String: Use the given string value instead of a code or a symbol. For example, an empty string will suppress the currency & symbol.
> - Boolean (marked deprecated in v5): true for symbol and false for code.
>
>   Optional. Default is 'symbol'.

Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

---

### No custom pipes needed

You can overwrite the currency & symbol with the string format.

> String: Use the given string value instead of a code or a symbol. For
>   example, an empty string will suppress the currency & symbol.

```
<span>{{ product.price | currency:'USD ' }}</span>
```

Comment: Add a space at the end of the currency string doesn't work. It will add space but it literally prints the currency.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new pipe that receive the currency as input.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'space'
})
export class SpacePipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
       console.log(value.substring(0, 1) + ' ' + value.substring( 1));
       return value.substring(0, 1) + ' ' + value.substring( 1);
   }
}
```

After that you can call them like this

```
{{discount | currency: 'EUR' | space}}
```

Dont forget to include it in @NgModule -> declarations

Answer (score 3):

Just concatenate the space as shown in the code below. It works`s for me. I am using Angular 6 by the way.

```
<span>{{ product.price | currency:'USD' + ' ' }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty complex solutions here when we can solve this problem with a simple workaround using angular pipes. Let's assume I want to display `USD 123`. The way we can do it is:

```
<div>
  {{0 | currency:'USD':'code' | slice:0:3}} {{<actualAmount> | number:'1.2-2'}}
</div>
```

What I am doing here is setting amount to 0 and then slicing off the currency code from it and then we can add the actual amount as a normal number.
Similarly for using symbol `$ 123`, we can do something like this:

```
<div>
  {{0 | currency:'USD':'symbol' | slice:0:1}} {{<actualAmount> | number:'1.2-2'}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{data|currency:'GBP'}}` you can use instead to `{{data|currency:'GBP':}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the display option with a custom string. Passing in a string currency code with the space added to the end instead of 'code' is working for me. Angular 13 though...

Answer (score -1):

Adding a space in the symbol section will also work. See below.

```
<strong class="d-inline-block">{{ amount | currency:"USD":"USD " }}</strong>
```

Comment: This doesn't show the correct symbol, just the string in the last part