# How i format this @pipe currency with space in angular?

Tags: angular

My pipe current print :

```
{{ 200 | currency:'BRL':true }} = R$200.00
```

I need include space between R$ in 200.00
would stay correct

```
{{ 200 | currency:'BRL':true }} = R$ 200.00`
```

somebody can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 CurrencyPipe space between currency and number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632192/angular-2-currencypipe-space-between-currency-and-number)

Comment: duplicate, I have a solved it by overriding default behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/a/46957677/1980774

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could chain a custom pipe to add a space

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'space'
})
export class SpacePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        return value.replace('R$', 'R$ ');
    }
}

{{ 200 | currency:'BRL':true | space }} // R$ 200.00
```

Comment: @TutiJapaWada Please consider marking a correct answer so we can all enjoy more internet points.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation of [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306668/3578809) answer that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195569/3578809). I added a small check since currency symbol is not always at the beginning. Hope this will be useful.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'space',
})
export class SpacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    // Check if first char is a currency symbol and not a number, then add space
    if (isNaN(value.charAt(0))) {
      // will add
      return value.substring(0, 1) + ' ' + value.substring(1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise return initial value
      return value;
    }
  }
}

{{ 634280 | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'': 'en-us' | space }} // € 634,280.00
```